# is there anything else than header / footer in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to write some details in 1 page in Word and in the second page I want the same details to be there.

There is only header / footer which can be the same what I want but the location of the details I want is in the center so header not benefit for me.

I hope you understand what I want

Comment: to explain what i want let say i have a letter of 2 pages i want the address be shown in first and second page, i want something that if i change the first page addresss the second page change automoticly

Comment: i want to write before and after it so both of header and footer will not help me as i can't write anytine before the header and anything after the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Header** to set your location to center. Just double click on the header area and hit `Enter` till your details appear at the center of the page.

[image]

Comment: thanks but i can't write anything above it if i press enter. to explain what i want let say i have a letter of 2 pages i want the address be shown in first and second page, i want something that if i change the first page addresss the second page change automoticly

Comment: I suggest you read the following articles. They will help you understand. [Link 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/header-and-footer-basics-RZ010239449.aspx), [Link 2](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/insert-headers-and-footers-HP001226486.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Place a text field into the header and position that text field where you want it to appear on the page. That should do the trick. Maybe you have to format the field to appear behind the text and/or set it to no-wrap.